# How to fix this xpath in selenium python?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath

I'm very new to this python and selenium world. Trying to automate some boring stuff with python using selenium webdriver. I'm having issues with below xpath. It seems `"="` messing things up.

Can anyone pls help ?

```
L = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id="ext-comp-1016"]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div[1]").click()

selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="ext-comp-1016"]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div[1]"}
  (Session info: chrome=87.0.4280.66)
```

Comment: You're using double-quoted string inside double-quoted string. Try to replace `"ext-comp-1016"` with `'ext-comp-1016'`

Comment: I did that, still get the same error :(

Comment: Can you add the HTML where yoj are trying to find this element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check if xpath works correctly on DOM page.
2. If xpath is correct I suggest to use implicit wait method. Probably runned script works faster than DOM page loading.

   ```
   from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
   from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
   from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

   L = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.Xpath,"/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div[1]"))).click()
   ```

Comment: Thanks, xpath works correctly on DOM page. 

Getting timeout now.
raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: Maybe put code in 'try except' block and use except block to catch screen. 
You'll see if expected webelement is visible. 

My assumption is that you can be on another site than you expect. Could you show me some more code to review it?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 issues-

1. You have written correct XPath syntax but while using it you kept it inside double quote and double quote is there in xpath as well, which is causing issue. So use this XPath inside single quote.
2. This XPath is very much fragile as it has indexes so it might be getting change when web page is reloading.

Solution-

1. Write a relative XPath using attribute and text value. When you write any xpath, verify that Xpath again after refreshing the page.
2. Try to put some wait time before looking for that element just to make sure that element is loaded in the page.